# need to add custom template file inside form container magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, widget-instance

What i have tried is the following.

I have a class which extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form`. Inside that i have the `_prepareLayout` function. Now i have set a block inside that function like this.

`echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/template')->setTemplate('path/tothefile.phtml')->toHtml();`

Its working. But the issue is i have a javascript code inside this .phtml file and its running twice.

May be because of the `core/text_list` block type of `widget` instance or for the `toHtml()` . Do you guys have any idea whats wrong.

Comment: have you specified that block in `layout.xml` ?

Comment: Why i should add it inside layout.xml ??...I was trying to add it from block. However i managed to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @KingshukDeb, how did you add a custom template file for the admin form?

Comment: @KingshukDeb `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text', 'example-block')->setText('<div id="messages"><ul class="messages"><li class="error-msg"><ul><li><span>CreateBlock.</span></li></ul></li></ul></div>')`

Answer (score 1):

Add `__toHtml()` method in form container block.

```
    protected function _toHtml() {
        $tabsContainer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text', 'example-block')->setText('<div id="messages"><ul class="messages"><li class="error-msg"><ul><li><span>CreateBlock.</span></li></ul></li></ul></div>');

        return parent::_toHtml() .
                $tabsContainer->toHtml() .
                '<div data id="tabs_container"></div>';
    }
```